# How to set keyboard shortcuts for switching to the previous/the next windows in Opera?

Tags: macos, opera

I use the most updated version of Opera on macOS (version:82.0.4227.33 (x86_64)). Cmd+` does not work for switching between windows. There are no menu items for switching between windows, and I can't find any entry for switching between windows in Configure Shortcuts (under Preferences > Advanced > Browser). How do I set keyboard shortcuts for switching to the previous/the next windows in Opera for macOS?

Comment: Not all apps have the 'Cycle through windows' menu item, but they should all respond to it anyway. You can check in Finder if that's the command it *ought* to be responding to, & you can change it in prefs - but if it won't respond to the original, I'm doubtful it will respond to a user change. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Answer (score 2):

Thank to Tetsujin for the comment, which has sent me in the right direction for a solution. What I have found out is as follows:

1. There is no menu item or setting for "Cycle through windows" in Opera. The keyboard shortcut for the function is just inherited from macOS's setting for "Move focus to next window" (found in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard).
2. If another keyboard shortcut set in Opera (under Preferences > Advanced > Browser > Configure shortcuts) is the same as macOS's shortcut for "Cycle through windows", the latter will be "shadowed" by the former.
3. What has happened in my case is that I have set macOS's setting for "Move focus to next window" to Ctrl + `, which happens to be the same as Opera's default setting for "Select previously active tab". Resolving the conflict brings back the expected behaviour.